# memcpy() copies more bytes than expected

Tags: c

I am trying to memcpy 'x' bytes from one array to another starting from some some offset within the array

```
strlen(buf) // source array already contains 144 bytes
// len - 500 bytes 
memcpy(&buf[start], &content[no_of_byes], len)
```

After this operation on performing strlen(buf), I am getting total of 752, instead of 644. I do not understand the reason.

I even tried copying 500 bytes from content array into another buffer2 and then copying it into buffer, still same result.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. The odds of memcpy being wrong are extremely low. You're probably not copying the NUL terminator, which begs the question, why are you using `memcpy` for strings? Or, why are you calling `strlen` on things that aren't strings?

Comment: strlen() of a buffer computes from the start of buf to first hit of null (\0) character. In your case, possibly null character is found at 752 position. I guess it has nothing to do with memcpy(), something to do with null character position

Comment: Buf is of length 2000, start offset- 144, no_of_byes offset- 0

Comment: Need to see more of that code.. There are possibilities that memcpy is "wrong" if for instance you didn't include the right `.h` and one of the arguments doesn't fit the prototype, resulting in UB (unlikely anyway), or if the src and dest are reversed, or if *len* is actually not correctly set (as it's not shown in your code) and is `< strlen(buf)+1`.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are looking for `strcat()` rather than `memcpy()`

Comment: Do you just need validation from anyone to say `memcpy()` has a bug? Or do you really have a valid question with your code which no one has seen?

Comment: What is the value of `buf` before the call to `memcpy()`? What is the value of `content`? What is the resulting value of `buf` after the call to `memcpy()`? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: `strlen` means "length of string", not "how many bytes did I `memcpy` just before"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strlen tries to calculate the length of a string, in the sense that it keeps on counting bytes from the beginning of the buffer till encounters a '\0' whereas memcpy works only with bytes.

I guess your problem stems from not understanding this.

You may be having a string of 752 and are trying copy some of the bytes inbetween from an offset to the beginning of the buffer (this info not very clear from your question). But, in this process, your '\0' probably remains at the same place leading to the strlen giving the same result.

My suggestion is to differentiate strings and normal buffers and use appropriate system calls for these two operations.